# Transposing ligand binding equation

Tags: transpose

Dear community members,

I am out of school for more than 10 years and now have to transpose an equation for my work to $x$. I already tried to find a solution, but failed. I would be very grateful for some explanations.

$$y = \frac{(Bx)}{(K+x)} + Nx$$

Thank you in advance,
Anton

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show your work and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on providing context in your question to better assist the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=\frac{Bx}{K+x}+Nx$$
$$y(K+x)=Bx+Nx(K+x)$$
$$yK+yx=Bx+NKx+Nx^2$$
$$Nx^2+(NK+B-y)x-Ky=0$$

Now use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

$$x=\frac{-NK-B+y\pm\sqrt{(NK+B-y)^2+4NKy}}{2N}$$

(there will be up to two solutions for $x$, taking the sign $+$ or $-$ in the numerator).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is subtract Nx from both sides: $y- Nx= \frac{Bx}{K+ x}$.

Now get rid of that fraction by multiplying both sides by K+ X:  $(y- Nx)(K+ x)= Ky-KNx+ xy- Nx^2= Bx$.

Combine all terms on the left side:
$Bx- KNx- xy- Nx^2+ Ky= 0$

Just because I like my leading term to be positive, multiply both sides by -1:
$Nx^2+ (KN- B- y)x- Ky- 0$.

Finally, since this involves "$x^2$" use the "Quadratic Formula" to solve for x:
$x= \frac{-KN+ B+ Y\pm\sqrt{(KN-B-y)^2+ 4NKy}}{2N}$

Comment: 3rd paragraph: $Bx$ goes to the left side and becomes $-Bx$.